# Programatically binding to a changing ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am creating an application that works like the 'wizard' component of some microsoft applications. To represent this, I have two ViewModels:

```
class WizardVm {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICommand QuitCommand { get { /* ommitted */ } }
    public WizardStepVm CurrentStep { get; set; }
}

class WizardStepVm {
    public string StepName { get; set; }
    public string StepText {get; set; }
}
```

In the view, `WizardVm` binds to a window, and `WizardStepVm`binds to a content panel inside the window. I am creating the content control programatically, and adding it to the WizardView like this:

```
// in the "DataContextChanged" handler for the WizardView
var bn = new Binding("CurrentStep");
bn.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;

var contentControl = new ContentControl();
contentControl.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, bn);
WizardViewStackPanel.Children.Add(contentControl);
```

This renders correctly when the WizardView is initially created. However, if `CurrentStep` changes, the view does not update to reflect this. CurrentStep changes, but ContentControl continues to display the original WizardStepVm. Also, the old WizardStepVm continues to exist in memory, and its string properties can still be changed (from the view).

Why is this? What do I have to do so that the content control changes to reflect changes in the ViewModel that it is bound to?

(There is actually a good reason for doing this programatically. However, xaml solutions are also appreciated.)

Comment: get rid off "//in the "DataContextChanged" handler for the WizardView". there is no need when doing MVVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class needs to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface to notify the UI every time
one of its properties changes:

```
class WizardStepVm : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    private string m_stepName;
    public string StepName {
      get {
        return m_stepName;
      }
      set {
        m_stepName = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("StepName");
      }
    }
    /* etc... */
}
```

Comment: Whoops! My class does implmenent this, and the property was set up to notify when it changed. However, the method that changes the selected step was accessing the underlying variable rather than the property.

Answer (score 2):

first of all your viewmodel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged or just use BindingMode OneTime.(see [this](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/10/detecting_bindings_that_should_be_onetime.html) post)

nevertheless you can do what you want very easily with viewmodel first approach and datatemplates

```
public class WizardVm {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public ICommand QuitCommand { get { /* ommitted */ } }
   public object CurrentStep { get; set; }//raise OnPropertyChanged("CurrentStep"); in your setter!!
}

public class WizardStep1Vm {
   public string StepName { get; set; }
   public string StepText {get; set; }
}

public class WizardStep2Vm {
   public string StepName { get; set; }
   public string StepText {get; set; }
}
```

window.xaml

```
<Window>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:WizardStep1Vm}">
        <!--your view for step1 goes here-->
        <local:MyStep1View/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:WizardStep2Vm}">
        <!--your view for step2 goes here-->
        <local:MyStep2View/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />

    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentStep}"/>

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

when ever you set the CurrentStep property in your viewmodel. you will see the right view in your contentcontrol. if not, the DataTemplate is missing ;)